# Stuck in zsh command trying to load .bash_profile after switching from bash on MacOS

Tags: command-line, bash, shell, git, zsh

I've just switched from `bash` to `zsh` on MacOS and I wanted to load my current `.bash_profile` so I did:

- Added `#!/bin/zsh` to my `.bash_profile` and ran:

```
% . ~/.bash_profile
```

And I was stuck because of this `bash` command to show `git` branch:

```bsh
export PS1="\[\033[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[0;33m\]\W\[\033[0;35m\]\$(parse_git_branch)\[\033[00m\]\$ "
```

And `zsh` just doesn't let me quit it. I've looked online and tried: `control + c, g, x, v` but none of them works.
I don't understand shells enough to figure out what's wrong with my `bash` command when I switched to `zsh`

Comment: How do you know this one command is to blame? Side note: when you source a file, `#!/bin/zsh` in it is just a comment, it makes no difference.

Comment: because when i sourced it, it was stuck in that line, which doesn't happen if i use bash. After commenting it out, zsh can load my profile normally.

Comment: My recommendation: don't use your bash init files to set up zsh! If you're only using zsh, rename the files to the proper `.z*` names and adjust their content as needed. If you're using both bash and zsh, create e.g. `.profile` for the common stuff, put bash-only stuff in `.bash_profile` and also `[ -f ~/.profile ] && . ~/.profile` to run the generic stuff; and put zsh-only stuff in `.zprofile` along with the same run-generic-profile command.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how anyone new to Zsh should start:

1. Back up any existing `rc` or `profile` files and remove them from your user dir.
2. Restart your shell. You will be greeted with the following:

```
This is the Z Shell configuration function for new users,
zsh-newuser-install.
You are seeing this message because you have no zsh startup files
(the files .zshenv, .zprofile, .zshrc, .zlogin in the directory
~).  This function can help you with a few settings that should
make your use of the shell easier.

You can:

(q)  Quit and do nothing.  The function will be run again next time.

(0)  Exit, creating the file ~/.zshrc containing just a comment.
  That will prevent this function being run again.

(1)  Continue to the main menu.

--- Type one of the keys in parentheses ---
```

3. Press <kbd>1</kbd>. This takes you to the following screen:

```
Please pick one of the following options:

(1)  Configure settings for history, i.e. command lines remembered
  and saved by the shell.  (Recommended.)

(2)  Configure the new completion system.  (Recommended.)

(3)  Configure how keys behave when editing command lines.  (Recommended.)

(4)  Pick some of the more common shell options.  These are simple "on"
  or "off" switches controlling the shell's features.  

(0)  Exit, creating a blank ~/.zshrc file.

(a)  Abort all settings and start from scratch.  Note this will overwrite
  any settings from zsh-newuser-install already in the startup file.
  It will not alter any of your other settings, however.

(q)  Quit and do nothing else.  The function will be run again next time.
--- Type one of the keys in parentheses ---
```

4. From here, go through menus 1 to 4 to configure things.
5. Finally, press <kbd>0</kbd> to save your settings into `~/.zshrc`.
6. Restart your terminal, start using the Z shell and don't worry about your old dotfiles.
7. Then, whenever you find that you are missing a feature from your old shell, you can try to selectively migrate it over from your old dotfiles.

This way, you'll run into the least amount of trouble and you'll be able to get rid of a lot junk from your old dotfiles in the process.